# How can I insert data into a MySQL Database from different sites?

Tags: mysql, .net, database

So I have a MySQL database that is accessible from the internet. I want to insert data into it from different sites (different domains / IP's) from a .net application. How should I go about this? Adding sites IP's to allow security access on the MySQL server is not feasible.

Comment: A open MySQL server to the internet is a security issue.. Also using MySQL hardcoded user name password combination in client programs because disassembler exists and can be used the get the login information.. Your best option is to close off the MySQL server from the internet and make a .NET HTTP REST API  which allows data access to the MySQL server and use that API for the client applications but what way you don't have trouble with firewalls because http traffic wil most likely not get blocked..

Comment: Don't have your client applications directly access the database.  Create a server web application which exposes an API to clients.  Secure the database so that only that server application can use it.  Close all other external access to the database.  Then have your client applications authenticate to the API, for which you have a variety of options.  Look into various authentication flows used in OAuth, for example.  Or even just manually issuing clients with randomized tokens which you can invalidate and re-issue any time you like.

Comment: Yes I absolutely agree with both of you. Create an API. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your server must not be localhost.
2. Configure your mysql database with the following code: `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
3. Uncomment the following lines of the file:

   - `skip-external-locking`
   - `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
4. the `bind-address IP` will be `0.0.0.0.`
5. restart your server: sudo service mysql restart
6. Granting permissions to the user or root or to the user with whom you work:

   - `mysql -u root -p`
   - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO root @ '%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`